# Web wallet making direct RPC calls to bitcoin node

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, wallet, json-rpc

Is it good idea to make direct RPC call's to node computer to generate web wallet addresses

here is what i am trying to implement
i want to create new web wallet based on bitcoin and want to allow the users to create their own wallet , and also send and receive the tokens or cryptocurrency

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it from front-end (web browser) it's not a good idea because you will expose an access to your bitcoin node so anyone able do anything with you bitcoin node, if you want to do it on the server so it is normal practice.

Just don't expose your RPC node access, allow connections only from localhost.

Comment: yes the frontend will be in angular 6 and backend will in django. Django will make further RPC calls to the node computer.

Comment: Further one question all the secured web wallet make RPC calls to the node ?[server to server calls ]

Comment: There is a lot of implementation opposite of RPC, some of them use IPC others communicate direct to the node.